# JS/ASP.Net: The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I Have a Problem with Javascript and ASP.Net

I have a page built in ASP.Net 4.0, with Ajax from DevExpress.
If I debug the project in Visual Studio 2010, the page works fine, even if I debug the javascript code in IE, where visual studio can debug the scripts.

When I publish the same page to a normal server, this doesn't work anymore.
An error occurs if I click a button that shows a modal popup. I want to use it as a loadingpanel for all postbacks, and this work fine with all other events and if a page is loading.

But if I click this button, the popup does not appear and IE shows the following error:

```
SCRIPT5022: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value
```

and if I debug the Javascript in IE, the error originates from this function:

```
_endPostBack: function PageRequestManager$_endPostBack(error, executor, data) {
        if (this._request === executor.get_webRequest()) {
            this._processingRequest = false;
            this._additionalInput = null;
            this._request = null;
        }

        var eventArgs = new Sys.WebForms.EndRequestEventArgs(error, data ? data.dataItems : {}, executor);
        Sys.Observer.raiseEvent(this, "endRequest", eventArgs);
        if (error && !eventArgs.get_errorHandled()) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: A shot into the dark. The reason for your first error message is a wrong formated date string that you passed from your client gui.

Comment: but i don't use dates... unless any argument from the event postback in javascript use a date, o i don't know what... because the explicit message "The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value" i can understand, but not understand in my code

Comment: and thanks for the edited, i not speak english...

Comment: I didn't write that you you use a date :-) The server tried to parse from the passed string to a datestring.